# problema para realizar un select de prestamo en jsp, valor de atributo clase Bean no valido

Tags: java, sql, jsp, date

estoy creando una gestión de préstamos en JSP y bueno, tengo un problema con el listado de los préstamos.

Aún no he creado un método para insertarlos, he introducido un préstamos en base de datos directamente usando MySQL para comprobar primero el método de listar los préstamos que están registrados.

El problema que hay es que cuando lanzo la aplicación me sale el siguiente error que os adjunto por pantalla con imagen.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Este es el menú donde le doy a Listado Completo

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Este es el error que se produce.

Os adjunto ahora los materiales que estoy usando para este tema en concreto.

1º-**La clase Prestamo, que está en un Package llamado Entidades**.

```
package Entidades;

import java.sql.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author AlbertoPortatil
 */
public class Prestamo {

int id;
String DNIusuario = null;
String ISBNobra = null;
Date Fechasolicitud = null;
Date Fechadevolucion = null;

public Prestamo(int id, String DNIusuario, String ISBNobra,
        Date Fechasolicitud, Date Fechadevolucion) {
    this.id = id;
    this.DNIusuario = DNIusuario;
    this.ISBNobra = ISBNobra;
    this.Fechasolicitud = Fechasolicitud;
    this.Fechadevolucion = Fechadevolucion;
}
  public Prestamo(String DNIusuario, String ISBNobra) {

    this.DNIusuario = DNIusuario;
    this.ISBNobra = ISBNobra;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDNIusuario() {
    return DNIusuario;
}

public void setDNIusuario(String DNIusuario) {
    this.DNIusuario = DNIusuario;
}

public String getISBNobra() {
    return ISBNobra;
}

public void setISBNobra(String ISBNobra) {
    this.ISBNobra = ISBNobra;
}

public Date getFechasolicitud() {
    return Fechasolicitud;
}

public void setFechasolicitud(Date Fechasolicitud) {
    this.Fechasolicitud = Fechasolicitud;
}

public Date getFechadevolucion() {
    return Fechadevolucion;
}

public void setFechadevolucion(Date Fechadevolucion) {
    this.Fechadevolucion = Fechadevolucion;
}

}
```

2º- **La clase DAO, donde os adjunto el select concreto para los préstamos.**

```
    package Entidades;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class DAO {
public ArrayList<Prestamo> selectPrestamo() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Prestamo> prestamos = null;

    try (Connection connection = DBConnection.get()) {
        if (connection == null) {//si la conexión es nula lanza una excepción
            throw new Exception("Connection is null");
        }

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM prestamo");

        prestamos = new ArrayList();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Prestamo prestamo = new Prestamo(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("DNIusuario"),
                    rs.getString("ISBNobra"), rs.getDate("Fechasolicitud"),
                    rs.getDate("Fechadevolucion"));
            prestamos.add(prestamo);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    return prestamos;
}
}
```

3º-**El SQL, el elemento que interesa es la tabla Prestamos**

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `prestamo`
--

    CREATE TABLE `prestamo` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `DNIusuario` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
      `ISBNobra` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
      `Fechasolicitud` date NOT NULL,
      `Fechadevolucion` date DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `prestamo`
--

    INSERT INTO `prestamo` (`id`, `DNIusuario`, `ISBNobra`, `Fechasolicitud`, `Fechadevolucion`) VALUES
    (1, '11111111A', '11111111A1', '2019-02-27', '2019-02-28');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Indices de la tabla `prestamo`
--

    ALTER TABLE `prestamo`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      ADD KEY `prestamo_ibfk_1` (`DNIusuario`),
      ADD KEY `prestamo_ibfk_2` (`ISBNobra`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `prestamo`
--

    ALTER TABLE `prestamo`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `prestamo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DNIusuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`DNI`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `prestamo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ISBNobra`) REFERENCES `obra` (`ISBN`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    COMMIT;

    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Y aquí la tabla préstamo con un registro que he metido para probar el select.**

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

4º-**La hoja jsp "HojaPrestamo",donde enlazo a otra hoja llamada formListarPrestamo.jsp, que es la que realiza el listado.**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>HojaUsuarios</title>
         <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="titulo">
            <h1>BIBLIOTECA - PRESTAMOS</h1>
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="opciones">
                    <h2><a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> <!--OK-->
                    <h2><a href="formListarPrestamo.jsp">Listado Completo</a></h2> <!--HACER-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**5º-y por ultimo La hoja formListarPrestamo.jsp, que es donde se produce el error.**

```
       <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="Entidades.Prestamo"%>
    <%@page import="Entidades.DAO"%>
    <%@page import="Entidades.DBConnection"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <jsp:useBean id="prestamo" class="Entidades.Prestamo" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="prestamo" property="*"/>
    <%
        String message = "";//por si hay que mandar un mensaje de error
        List<Prestamo> prestamos = null;
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        try {

            prestamos = dao.selectPrestamo();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            message = ex.toString();

        }

    %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>formListarPrestamo</title>
        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="titulo">
            <h1>BIBLIOTECA - PRESTAMOS</h1>
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="opciones">
                    <h2><a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> 
                </div>
                <form>
                    <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                    <input name="status_initial" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                    <%} else { %>

                    <br/><br/>

                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>

                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>DNI Usuario</th>
                            <th>ISBN Obra</th>
                            <th>FechaSolicitud</th>
                            <th>FechaDevolucion</th>
                        </tr>
                        <!--creación de una tabla para mostrar todos los objetos prestamo-->
                        <%for (int i = 0; i < prestamos.size(); i++) {%>
                        <tr>

                            <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getId()%></td>
                            <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getDNIusuario()%></td>
                            <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getISBNobra()%></td>
                            <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getFechasolicitud()%></td>
                            <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion()%></td>

                        </tr>                            
                        <%}%>
                    </table>
                    <%}%>
                </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUK8q.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgfLk.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPJhP.png
```

No sé si hay que poner los atributos de la clase de otra forma o si la base de datos tiene algo mal en fecha solicitud o devolución, los préstamos en todo caso van a tener las fechas del sistema y su devolución será considerada con retraso después de pasar 10 días desde esa fecha, pero bueno, es un dato que os doy.

Perdón por la extensión, pero he considerado que había que mostrar todas las partes implicadas (no he puesto la conexión, pero bueno, no creo que sea relevante).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estupendo, he logrado que funcione, solo había que añadir un constructor vacío en la clase Prestamo, la cual quedaría así.

```
public class Prestamo {

int id;
String DNIusuario = null;
String ISBNobra = null;
Date Fechasolicitud = null;
Date Fechadevolucion = null;

public Prestamo(){}
public Prestamo(int id, String DNIusuario, String ISBNobra,
        Date Fechasolicitud, Date Fechadevolucion) {
    this.id = id;
    this.DNIusuario = DNIusuario;
    this.ISBNobra = ISBNobra;
    this.Fechasolicitud = Fechasolicitud;
    this.Fechadevolucion = Fechadevolucion;
}
  public Prestamo(String DNIusuario, String ISBNobra) {

    this.DNIusuario = DNIusuario;
    this.ISBNobra = ISBNobra;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDNIusuario() {
    return DNIusuario;
}

public void setDNIusuario(String DNIusuario) {
    this.DNIusuario = DNIusuario;
}

public String getISBNobra() {
    return ISBNobra;
}

public void setISBNobra(String ISBNobra) {
    this.ISBNobra = ISBNobra;
}

public Date getFechasolicitud() {
    return Fechasolicitud;
}

public void setFechasolicitud(Date Fechasolicitud) {
    this.Fechasolicitud = Fechasolicitud;
}

public Date getFechadevolucion() {
    return Fechadevolucion;
}

public void setFechadevolucion(Date Fechadevolucion) {
    this.Fechadevolucion = Fechadevolucion;
}
```

}